# How can cyclic quorum ever come to a consensus?

Tags: consensus

Consider the simplest case with three nodes `A, B, C`, with:

```
Q(A) = {{A,B}}
Q(B) = {{B,C}}
Q(C) = {{C,A}}
```

So a cyclic graph. How can this ever reach consensus? In order for `A` to make a decision, he goes to `B` for advice, in order for `B` to make a decision, he goes to `C` for advice, and in order for `C` to make a decision, he has to go to `A` for advice. Wouldn't this be perpetual?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way the SCP protocol works, you include your quorum slices in your vote messages.  So following your example, nodes would say the following:

- A says. "I vote to accept statement *a* so long as B accepts it, too."
- B says, "I vote to accept statement *a* so long as C accepts it, too."
- C says, "I vote to accept statement *a* so long as A accepts it, too."

So now the nodes multicast their votes around, and each node needs to ask itself whether a quorum voted for *a*.  Well, the set of nodes that voted for *a* is U = {A, B, C}.  Is U a quorum?  It's a quorum if it contains a slice of each of its members, and as it happens, it does:

- {A,B} is a slice for A and a subset of U
- {B,C} is a slice for B and a subset of U
- {C,A} is a slice for C and a subset of U

So yes, U is a quorum and the quorum then accepts statement *a*.

The key is that you don't have to accept something to vote for it.  The vote message you broadcast is conditioned on other people voting the same way.